# Python: How to override text area in form using CSS

Tags: python, html, css

Hi I would like to ask on how to override the text area in  form using CSS.
This is my codes:

forms.py

```
description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'comment-control'}))
```

CSS:

```
.comment-control {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 830px;
    height: 110px;
}
```

HTML

```
<form name="add_comment" id="comment-form"  action="{% url 'comment:create' refId=refApp.id refApp=thisApp %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
    </form>
```

I want to change the layout of the textarea of form using CSS but it is not being inherited, I appreciate your help. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should do something like this:

```
description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols':'4', 'rows':'50'}))
```